# How to solve this system of equations with complex exponential in MATLAB?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, matlab, signal-processing, least-squares

Given $\Delta t$, I want to solve in MATLAB the following system of equations with complex exponentials in unknowns $\alpha_k$ and $\nu_k$

$$\lambda_k = \exp \left((-\alpha_k + j2\pi\nu_k)\Delta t)\right)$$

where $k = 1, 2, \dots, K$ and $\lambda_k$ is a complex vector of size $K$.  I am trying to find ways that is better than symbolic method. Could someone suggest me a simpler solution that can handle large $K$?

Comment: What is the exponential of a vector?

Comment: I have edited it further.  They are unknows for $k = 1,2,...,K$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Using de Moivre's identity and calling $\lambda_k = x_k + i y_k$ we have

$$
\cases{
2\pi\nu_k\Delta t = \arctan\left(\frac{y_k}{x_k}\right)\\
e^{-\alpha_k\Delta t}=\sqrt{x_k^2+y_k^2}
}
$$

Comment: Thank you, I got this.  Is there any function available in Matlab (for eg. bsxfun) that I can use in this case to simplify this step instead of deriving it and then coding it?